# Closeness of measures on a cardinal

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, large-cardinals

Given an uncountable $\kappa$ and a $\kappa$-complete nontrivial non-normal ultrafilter on $\kappa$, and some $g:\kappa\to\kappa$ with $<_{U}$-rank $\kappa$ (where $f_0<_Uf_1$ iff $\{i<\kappa\, |\, f_0(i)<f_1(i)\}\in U$), we can define a normal ultrafilter $D = \{ X\subseteq \kappa\, |\, g^{-1}(X)\in U\}$ and an embedding $k:Ult(V,D)\to Ult(V,U)$ by $k([f]_D)= [f\circ g]_U$. I see that $\kappa < crit(k) \leq [id_{\kappa}]_U<(2^{\kappa})^+$ and I was wondering if anything more can be said (in ZFC) about $crit(k)$, and otherwise what values of $crit(k)$ are consistent, and for example if it's consistent that $\kappa$ is measurable, there exist non-normal measures on $\kappa$ and always this $crit(k)=[id_{\kappa}]_U$. Basically, I would be glad to be pointed at any result that could make this more clear for me.

Comment: Why is $D$ normal?

Comment: @AsafKaragila $D$ is normal because $g$ represents $\kappa$ in the ultrapower by $U$.  In more detail, if $f$ is regressive on a set in $D$, then $f\circ g<_Ug$ and therefore $f\circ g$ is constant on a set in $U$, which makes $f$ constant on a set in $D$.

Comment: @Andreas: Ohh, I missed the part where the $<_U$-rank is $\kappa$.

Comment: I like this question a great deal. As a quick comment, you can show that $\kappa^+<\mathrm{cp}(k)$, so if GCH holds everything lives between $\kappa^+$ and $\kappa^{++}$. Furthermore, $\mathrm{cp}(k)$ must have cofinality $\kappa^+$ (in $V$).

Comment: Thank you for the contribution, Miha. Could you explain why $cof(cp(k))\leq \kappa^+$ ? I understand the rest.

Comment: I take my comment back; there doesn't seem to be a reason why $\mathrm{cf}(\mathrm{cp}(k))\leq\kappa^+$ (unless, of course, GCH holds).

Comment: I wonder if this is easy to answer in $L[U]$. Can we say what happens with the critical points of the successive factor embeddings when we iterate a measure?

Comment: I checked that for a two-step iteration by a normal measure, $V\to M_1 \to M_2$, the $k$ obtained from the map from $V$ to $M_2$ is the same as the map from $M_1$ to $M_2$. And the embedding of $V$ to $M_2$ is an ultrapower embedding for a product ultrapower on $\kappa\times \kappa$, but we could make that into an ultrapower on $\kappa$ with Gödel pairing. So in this case the critical point of $k$ is $j_1(\kappa)$ when $j_1:V\to M_1$ is the ultrapower embedding for the normal measure on $\kappa$.

Comment: Ok. In fact your conclusion is true for any iteration of the normal measure; the factor map $k$ is simply the tail of the iteration, omitting the first step. Therefore, since in $L[U]$ every measure on $\kappa$ is an iterate of the normal measure, $\mathrm{cp}(k)=j_1(\kappa)$ regardless of the measure used. It would now suffice to build a measure on $\kappa$ for which $[\mathrm{id}]\neq j_1(\kappa)$ Can the normal measure be permuted somehow to get this?